# OpenGL Texture Bitmap Offset Issue

Tags: c, opengl, bitmap, texture-mapping, texture2d

I'm trying to load a bitmap image and then use that as a texture to apply to a polygon. Most of this is working, but the bitmap appears to be offset:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int width = 64;
int height = 64;
unsigned char * data = NULL;

void load_image_data(const char * image_path)
{
    FILE * file = fopen(image_path, "rb");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open <%s>!\n", image_path);
        exit(1);
    }

    data = calloc(width * height * 3, sizeof(unsigned char));

    fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
}

void display(void)
{
    GLuint texture;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
    glVertex2i(0, height);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
    glVertex2i(width, height);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
    glVertex2i(width, 0);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    load_image_data("squares.bmp");

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Squares!");

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling this with the following command:

```
gcc squares.c -g -o squares -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

And then executing it with:

```
./squares
```

Here is the image that I'm using:

[image: Original]

And then here is the screenshot of the program once it is executed :

[image]

I can't seem to find any reason for this.

I have also read about the bitmap format, and have tried offsetting the data read by `fread()` by 54 bytes in order to skip the header - but this has had no effect.

***EDIT #1 (by author)***:

I decided to do some additional testing. It seems the part of the image that starts from the origin (0,0 = bottom left corner) is pushed up 1 pixel, and takes what would be the right-most 18 pixels of the image.

This appears to be constant, no matter what the size of the image is. (Currently using a 64x64 pixel image).

So, it's offset by -18,-1 - but when it gets to the part of where the image ACTUALLY starts, the -1 is reset to 0 ...If that makes sense... It doesn't to me.

Comment: Why was so much context from my original question removed? Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel pretty silly. When I stated that I had tried to read the header of the BMP - I was doing it wrong. Or at least setting the 54 byte offset in the wrong argument.

Regardless, the solution was to change the `load_image_data()` function to the following:

```
void load_image_data(const char * image_path)
{
    FILE * file = fopen(image_path, "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open <%s>!\n", image_path);
        exit(1);
    }

    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, file);

    width = *(int *) &info[18];
    height = *(int *) &info[22];

    data = calloc(width * height * 3, sizeof(unsigned char));

    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), width * height * 3, file);
    fclose(file);
}
```